# ReSharper / VS 2010: How to disable HTML closing tag insertion

Tags: visual-studio-2010, formatting, resharper

- ReSharper Full Edition v6.0.2202.688
- Visual Studio 2010 Professional SP1

As an example, when I type `<div` and hit `space` or close the start tag ReSharper inserts the closing `</div>` tag.  I don't want it to do this.  I know there is a corresponding Visual Studio setting which does the same thing, which I have already disabled but makes no difference as ReSharper seems to do it in its own way.

VS setting:

`Tools > Options > Text Editor > HTML > Formatting > "Auto insert close tag"`

I have scoured the web for answers and the closest thing I can find is that there *may* be a bug in some versions of ReSharper which causes this, but I have been unable to properly confirm that.

Comment: I don't see this happening with the latest ReSharper 6.1. Switching off the VS native option successfully prevents inserting the closing tag. On another note, why does this option bother you? Is it due to working with WebForms (ItemTemplates and related things), or otherwise?

Comment: Thanks, I will see if I can upgrade and if that fixes the issue.  I mostly don't want it because when I do things like wrap an existing block of markup with something like a <div> it puts the closing tag at the top, which I then have to delete and add below the block I am trying to surround.  Also I touch-type so autocomplete stuff like this is often just a hindrance.

Comment: For wrapping existing blocks, try [Extend/Shrink Selection](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/coding_assistance.html#ExtendShrink_Selection) followed by a [surround template](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_templates.html#Surround_With_Templates) I touch-type, too, and this has never been a hindrance. Finally, as you're using 6.0, 6.1 is a free upgrade.

Comment: I'd rather just turn off the annoying feature in the product than have to change the way I work most productively.

Comment: Trying new things never hurts, especially if those things serve to streamline your specific scenario. Which doesn't mean you shouldn't turn the auto-insertion off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed to respect VS option in 6.1. Please upgrade.